# How to use react native image onError get error message?

Tags: image, react-native

I use react native v0.44 image component for android , but image can not load , code:

```
<View style={styles.slide1} key={index}>
                  <Image
                    style={styles.image}
                    resizeMode = 'contain'
                    onError = {(e)=>{
                      console.log(e)
                    }}
                    source={{uri:`http://i01.appmifile.com/webfile/globalimg/hk/cms/92247F5D-CC6E-273F-5710-841E891CB96F.jpg`}}
                  />
                </View>
```

the image can't show , onError handle get error , but how to know what error in load image ?

Comment: Did you figure this one out? I can't figure out why my image is erroring. There doesnt seem to be anything inside `e.nativeEvent` and there is no `e.error`.

Comment: any solutions? @Mark Zhang

Answer (score -1):

Error contains nativeEvent and its error.
Do like this:

```
onError={({nativeEvent: {error}}) => {
    console.log(error);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Your onError function is as it should be.

But remember, when you use remote picture you need to define width and height for Image.

Comment: this answer is not relevant to the question asked.